# jackcess delete row and set autoincrement column

Tags: java, jackcess

1. How delete row from table with help jackcess?
   I try so, but it's bad:

   ```
       Table ptabl = db.getTable("person");
       int pcount = ptabl.getRowCount();
       for (int i = 0; i < pcount; i++) {
           Map<String, Object> row2 = ptabl.getNextRow();
           if (row2.get("id") == Integer.valueOf(1)) {
               ptabl.deleteCurrentRow();
           }
       }
   ```
2. How set column "id" attribute to autoincrement?

   `Table newTable = new TableBuilder("diagnosis").
   addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("id")
   .setSQLType(Types.INTEGER)
   .toColumn())
   .addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("name")
   .setSQLType(Types.VARCHAR)
   .toColumn()).toTable(db);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your id column is indexed, you can use an IndexCursor to quickly find columns:

```
IndexCursor cursor = new CursorBuilder(ptabl).setIndexByColumnNames("id").toIndexCursor();
if(cursor.findFirstRowByEntry(1)) {
  cursor.deleteCurrentRow();
}
```

If your id column is not indexed, you can use a normal cursor, which is more convenient but effectively no faster than your current code (just does a table scan):

```
Cursor cursor = new CursorBuilder(ptab1).toCursor();
Column idCol = ptab1.getColumn("id");
if(cursor.findFirstRow(idCol, 1)) {
  cursor.deleteCurrentRow();
}
```

And your own answer indicates you already figured out how to make a column auto increment.

Answer (score 1):

For set autoincrement to column:

```
Table newTable = new TableBuilder("diagnosis").addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("id").setAutoNumber(true).setSQLType(Types.INTEGER).toColumn()).addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("name").setSQLType(Types.VARCHAR).toColumn()).toTable(db);
```