# how to delete a row with auto increment as primary key in netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am a newbie to java and I am using netbeans

I want to delete a row from my database (mysql) by clicking on the row in a table during run time and click button delete but I used auto increment for the primary key of the row 
I do not know how to specify the primary key column

these are not working for me

```
delete from admin where adminID = default
delete from admin where adminID = adminID
```

Comment: The same way as any other column?

Comment: and what is your complete code of deletion ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343470/jackcess-delete-row-and-set-autoincrement-column

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem like yours if you don't want to show the primary key column in JTable.What i did is to add the primary key column to my table and hid the primary key column.

I hide the column using this code :

```
TableColumn column = table.getColumn(columnName);
table.removeColumn(column);
```

And I get the value using :

```
int row = table.getSelectedRow();
table.getModel().getValueAt(row, columnIndex).toString();
```

So the code to delete the row became :

```
pst = conn.prepareStatement("delete from admin where adminID = ?");
pst.setString(1,table.getModel().getValueAt(row, columnIndex).toString());
pst.execute();
```

Hope it helps you...

Comment: Don't concatenate literals into SQL statements, use a `PreparedStatement` instead

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name,I just give a example but I'm gonna edit it soon

Comment: Thanks Guys im very grateful



This is what i did but columname (adminID in the following line) is giving error 
TableColumn column = tblAdministractor.getColumn(adminID); //the column name is adminID in the database
 
 tblAdministractor.removeColumn(column);
 
  

int row = tblAdministractor.getSelectedRow();
tblAdministractor.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1).toString();

pst = con.prepareStatement("delete from admin where adminID = ?");
pst.setString(1,tblAdministractor.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1).toString());

pst.execute();

Comment: i fixed that by using ("adminID") yet isnt deleting

Comment: Are sure adminID column on second column in JTable ?

Comment: adminID is on 1st column nt second if that is what you are asking. Another thing i forgot to tell you is i have a table call person with has a foreign key in admin table

Comment: Try to set second parameter method getValueAt to 0.If still doesn't work then show what program error is or possible algorithm error of your code.

Comment: thanks everytin work out fine im grateful for your time.... the new problem i am having now is i want to be able to move around my jpanel during runtime. thanks once again

Comment: ok,your welcome.Maybe you need to create new topic so that everyone can see your problem.

Comment: I don't know it but you can search it on google.Try to search before asking :D